# Copy paste link in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, copy, paste

I am getting a runtime error '438' on the paste line. help?

```
Sub xyz()
    For r = 6 To 84 Step 39
        For c = 3 To 36 Step 3
             reportcopy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c).Resize(31, 3)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

this function calls the bottom one

```
Private Sub reportcopy(InRange As Range)
    InRange.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Paste Link:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` is a `Range`, and there is no `Range.Paste` method. You need to use [`Worksheet.Paste`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste), as demonstrated in the linked thread.

Comment: @BigBen i tried worksheet, activesheet, activecell and it doesnt work

Comment: @BigBen i am getting an 1004 error - Paste method of Worksheet Class Failed

Comment: Try `With Sheets("Report")`, `.Activate`, `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select`, `.Paste Link:=True`, `End With`.

Comment: @BigBen error1004 MIcrosoft Excel cant paste the data.

Comment: Maybe use the macro recorder and record yourself doing the paste link manually, then inspect the recorded code. The last provided code works for me in testing. Do you have merged cells on the Report sheet?

Comment: no merge on sheets. see entire edited code above^^

Comment: maybe reopen question so others an answer @BigBen

Comment: Using the `xyz` code together with the last snippet I provided works perfectly for me in testing. Your question as-is is a duplicate, because `Range` does not have a `Paste` method.